# Should users profile pictures be vetted in some way?

Tags: discussion, gravatar, inappropriate-content

I noticed a [user on SU](https://superuser.com/users/542?tab=accounts#sort-top) just now with a profile picture that I think could possibly be considered inappropriate.

Firstly, does anyone agree. Do you think this is inappropriate? When I first saw the image by his name in a post I genuinely thought it was some kind of symbol because the user was an admin.

(To hyperslug, if you read this please don't take offence that I am discussing you, I just think your image could be misleading, particularly to new users who could be lead to believe you are some kind of administrator)

Comment: I presume we're not talking about the five stars here.

Comment: Hm, just found this thread, never got an email or anything.  Gravatar changed to avoid any potential confusion.  @Simon, no prob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would propose a way to flag a user, perhaps a link in their profile to get moderator attention. There should also be a moderator tool to remove a users gravatar in a case like the above.

Comment: Yes, I think it is would be a good idea if mods can remove/change users images (perhaps they already can). There probably isn't the need to allow users to flag other users as this is probably a fairly rare case, posting here pretty much can cover than case. I know gravatar restricts x rated content, but I'm sure there are plenty of images like this that are inappropriate in the context of the site, but are allowed past gravatars filtering.

Comment: The trick here is that the only way to remove the Gravatar is to remove the email address itself, so while it might be worth it in the most egregious situations, I think that perhaps a mechanism to disable the Gravatar might be a useful mod option to disable the display of the image but retain the email for contact (and user notification) purposes.

Comment: An interesting request from someone that I am starting to doubt is really the POTUS.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't bother me in any way.  I suppose I can see how people might get confused by that image, but I don't see a reason to preemptively start moderating such things based upon the *possibility* of abuse or confusion.  Let it be looked into if it becomes a problem, not before.  If it *were* a problem, or if the image were simply inappropriate, you could try flagging a random answer or question by the user in order to notify the moderators about it, or just email the SO team directly.

On a related note, Gravatar has a rating system to allow sites to restrict the images that are allowed.  In major WTF fashion, though, it is the user himself who determines the rating.  And there doesn't seem to be a way to flag inappropriate images.  Either I'm missing something or the people over at Gravatar have way more faith in humanity than I do.

Comment: isn't the correct word 'was' instead of 'were'?

Comment: http://en.gravatar.com/site/abuse/

Comment: @Chacha102: No.  Conditional phrasing means subjunctive mood.  Think *Fiddler on the Roof*: "if I **were** a rich man."

Comment: @Shog9: Shut up.  Nobody likes a know-it-all.

Comment: I like a know-it-all, as long as they're correcting someone else.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a way to restrict the images presented, like being able to flag them.  I don't have a problem with the example, but I saw one yesterday that was less than family friendly, and I had no way to flag it.

Comment: http://en.gravatar.com/site/abuse/

Comment: Thanks, I'll be doing that next time I see it, but I think it'd still be good for SO to have an image flagging mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You can always flag one of his posts for moderator attention with an according message. If they take any action then probably depends on how often the user gets flagged.

I don't think there is any need for a special flag on the user/icon itself.

Answer (score 0):

Meh. Your title and the use of "innapropriate" made me expect something else. I don't really see *this* as a problem. I was expecting something a bit more...well....

Comment: ...racy? ...naughty? Check this profile to get your fix: http://stackoverflow.com/users/342/graham-reeds

Comment: X's instead of stars?

Answer (score 0):

You can [report abuse of gravatar images](http://en.gravatar.com/site/abuse/)