# How can we report people for bad icon/avatars?

Tags: feature-request, gravatar, offensive, reporting

No offense to [Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138984/nick-brooks), but I don't care for pedobear and find it offensive. Is there a way to report that, or future icons that may be worse?

Comment: Why don't you have a seat right over here...

Comment: I edited in a link in my answer to the Gravatar abuse reporting webpage.

Comment: I'm deeply offended by pug dogs.  I insist you replace your avatar immediately.

Comment: I had no idea it was offensive. Thank you for making me stare at that thing long enough to get it. Now my brain is ruined.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12018/should-users-profile-pictures-be-vetted-in-some-way

Comment: Either you know who or what pedobear is **or** you are offended by it. Those options are mutually exclusive. If they aren't for you, I suggest you stop using the internet **now**.

Comment: I agree with Manni. I think people being offended by things on the internet is a bit silly, but I guess trolls need to be fed by somebody. Perhaps we need a tollkeeper badge for people who flag posts as offensive too often.

Comment: @Mark: If you don't care, how can you then be offended?

Comment: gosh , i've changed it already

Comment: 2019 update: I love love LOVE how this is somehow off topic for meta stack exchange. That is so terribly Stack Overflow of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just googled that, and I agree.  You can complain to [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/site/abuse/) directly also.

Comment: You typed "Pedo..." In to Google?... Careful!... But +1, good answer.

Comment: I figured that the word 'pedobear' in the text search would be ok, but I was nervous doing it from work.

Comment: @Lance Roberts - That is what your smart phone is for.

Comment: Just looking into getting one, pretty pricey in Alaska ($70/mo).

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps you should consider changing your home page from [Nick's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138984/nick-brooks) to something else so you don't have to look at it that often?

I'm sure that 99% of people (myself included) had no idea where Nick's avatar came from until this thread. And now that I do I still don't care; the picture **by itself** is not offensive in any way.

Comment: Sure, but the point still stands. What if the picture WAS something far more offensive?

Comment: @Farseeker - See Æther's answer for why that's probably not possible.

Comment: I guess it's the difference between this being a site used by professionals, and not. I don't want my coworkers or boss to see that icon on my screen when I'm looking something up at work. Sorry if my being offended by a "humorous" pedophile icon bothers you.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use the "Contact us" link at the bottom of every page.

But I think you are being too touchy in this case.

Comment: @dmckee - I would have to agree with you.  I do not know who pedobear was until I googled it.

Comment: @Michael - I find it interesting that you're referring to pedobear as a "who."

Answer (score 6):

Yes, reporting it here usually works. On this *specfic* occasion, I'm inclined to agree with @ChssPly76 and @dmckee, rather than jump in and remove it (which we have done before).

Answer (score 5):

Gravatar already has a [reporting mechanism](http://en.gravatar.com/site/abuse/), and [SO only accepts G- or PG-rated images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/my-profile-picture-is-not-taken-from-gravatar).

As for an image that would be possibly "offensive" to SO while still a PG-acceptable image: the only case I can recall is the parody of Jeff Atwood's avatar a few months back.  (Some Nazi symbolism came up recently too, but if I recall that was dealt with via Gravatar directly.)

Comment: The same user (as the parody) used to have a gravatar of Jesus flipping the bird - which he was asked to change.

Comment: @Jon B - That's just Rich B. This is unrelated to him and his shenanigans.