# How to report inappropriate avatars now that Gravatar provides no method of doing so?

Tags: support, gravatar, offensive, reporting

[Used to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33688/how-can-we-report-people-for-bad-icon-avatars), the thing to do was to report sketchy avatars through Gravatar. They no longer appear to have anything resembling a way to do that — there's no obvious way to get from an avatar image URL to the right profile, and there's no links anywhere I can see (on my own profile or the general site or what passes for their help) to report abuse. What are our options now?

(In one such case, I tried ♦ flagging a week ago, but the flag is still pending.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're always welcome to report it to us directly, either by flagging it or use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, as we can forcibly change a Gravatar on a user's profile to use the Identicon instead of their actual image. Granted, this does allow the user to easily change it back, but doing so would likely just lead to a suspension for that user.

You *can* still report avatar abuse to Gravatar, they just made it somewhat complicated to do so. Since you'll only have the image URL, you'll have to work with that. What you really need is the Gravatar hash which generates the image. For example, my image path is:

```
https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3c448146cc10087c31a564800bdb6ca6
```

With that hash at the end, you can then get to their Gravatar profile by removing all the junk: the `secure.` at the beginning and the `/avatar` in the middle, so you just have `gravatar.com/{hash}` as a URL. Then, go to that URL.

This will redirect you to the user's profile page on Gravatar. From there, you can click the **Report Abuse** link at the bottom of the left-hand column and explain that the user has an inappropriate avatar for the content rating where it is being used (we use the PG rating on our sites).

Comment: Ah, OK. I dug around but couldn't find any documentation for that URL transform, so I dead-ended at my own Gravatar profile.