# Flag user avatar

Tags: discussion, flags, profile-picture, offensive

This question is related to flagging a profile I presume, which is an open problem-but I was wondering-

> Is there a specific way to flag an offensive avatar image?

Or do I need to somehow contact the moderators of the particular stack in another way  (mail?).

Comment: @rene It does not address the issue of how to flag it-unless I am missing some obvious feature as a user..

Comment: That post says "Flag any post that the user has written for moderator attention and / or contact us to let us know about it." On *some* sites, you can often grab a moderator on chat, but there's no email, or off post batsignal for it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Well, I suppose this answers my question in the sense that there is no such feature available at this time. The issue from which this question stems is that the said profile picture can be perceived as offensive only by a certain ethnic group-or from someone who has an understanding of that group's language and cultural nuances. The chance that a "random" moderator will see this is highly unlikely. I guess I will have to explain it in chat. Anyway, thanks to both of you (JG & Rene..).

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake kinda unusual that people find a offensive profile post *and* there's no questions or answers to flag.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Well, the answers-questions the user posts are of a high quality and contribute generally to the stack, I see absolutely no issue with them whereas their profile picture could result in someone getting killed in a real life situation..

Comment: Oh, its fine to "abuse" a post for a flag there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Well i suppose that willbe the proper course of action! Thanks again! If you wish I will delete this in order to avoid duplicates.

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33688/how-can-we-report-people-for-bad-icon-avatars/33701#33701